# wix: Service is not being started after rollback

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

We have a wix project. It installs two Windows Services and a windows desktop application which will be shown in the task bar tray icon. The purpose of these two services is to watch each other and the desktop application so that if any one of the service is not running, the other service will start it. And if the desktop application is not running, one of the two services will start the desktop application.

We want to implement the rollback feature in our installer so that if there is any error during the upgrade to latest version, the installer will be rollback to the previous existing version. We are testing the rollback using the  WixFailWhenDeferred.

```
<CustomActionRef Id="WixFailWhenDeferred" />
```

The rollback seems to work as in the tests, the install rollbacks to previous versions. For example, in the machine v8.0.1.0 is already installed and when we run the following command, it tries to install v8.0.2.0 but finally rollbacks to 8.0.1.0.

```
>msiexec.exe /passive /norestart /i "D:\setup8.0.2.0.msi" /L*vx+ "d:\test\Installlog8.0.2.0.log"   WIXFAILWHENDEFERRED=1
```

1. But, we have one issue. If the 8.0.1.0 is already installed in the machine and we double click the newer version 8.0.2.0.msi, then it will ask to close the existing desktop application. I mean, it shows the File in use dialog box.
2. In the above command line, if we remove the /passive argument, then it also shows the File in use dialog box.
3. Also, the service is not being started after the rollback.
4. So, is something missing in our wix project?

The wix code

```
 <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
```

The custom actions

```
 <CustomAction Id="CertificateInstallCustomAction"
              BinaryKey="CertificateCustomActions.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="InstallClientCertificate"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check" 
              Impersonate="no" />

<CustomAction Id="CertificateRemoveCustomAction"
              BinaryKey="CertificateCustomActions.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="UninstallClientCertificate"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no"/>

<CustomAction Id="ClientInstallCustomAction"
              BinaryKey="ClientCustomActions.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="InstallValidation"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check" 
              Impersonate="no"/>  

  <CustomAction Id="ClientInstallCustomActionRoll"
              BinaryKey="ClientCustomActions.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="InstallValidation"
              Execute="rollback"
              Return="ignore" />  

<CustomAction Id="ClientRemoveCustomAction"
              BinaryKey="ClientCustomActions.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="UninstallValidation"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="check"/>

<CustomAction Id="StartServiceIfNotRunningIdRoll"
              BinaryKey="ClientCustomActions.CA.dll"
              DllEntry="StartServiceIfNotRunning"
              Execute="rollback"
              Return="ignore" />
```

ClientRemoveCustomAction: This custom action is to kill the desktop application before uninstallation.

The sequence

```
<CustomAction  Id='AlreadyInstalled' Error='You are running the same version of [ProductName] as you are trying to install.' />
<CustomActionRef Id="WixFailWhenDeferred" />
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <!--<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" />-->
  <Custom Action='AlreadyInstalled' After='FindRelatedProducts'>SAME_VERSION_INSTALLED</Custom>

  <Custom Action="CertificateInstallCustomAction" After="InstallServices">
    (NOT Installed) AND (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) <!-- For install -->
  </Custom>
  <Custom Action="CertificateRemoveCustomAction" After="CertificateInstallCustomAction">
    (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL") <!-- For Unintall-->
  </Custom>
  <Custom Action="ClientInstallCustomAction" Before="CertificateInstallCustomAction" >
    (NOT Installed) AND (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) OR (NOT Installed)<!-- For install-->
  </Custom>
  <Custom Action="ClientInstallCustomActionRoll" Before="ClientInstallCustomAction" >
    (Installed OR NOT Installed)
  </Custom>
  <Custom Action='ClientRemoveCustomAction' Before='InstallValidate'>
    (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL") OR (REMOVE) <!--  For Unintall and Upgrade, we need to ask the uninstall password-->
  </Custom>
  <Custom Action='StartServiceIfNotRunningIdRoll' After='InstallInitialize'>
   (Installed)  <!--This is only for restart the service in case of Rollback.--> 
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The services

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ClientServices" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="ABCWD.exe" Guid="*">
    <File Id="ABCWD.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ClientSourceDirectory)\ABCWD.exe" />
    <wix:ServiceInstall Id="ABCWDServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Name="Service1" DisplayName="Service1" 
                        Description="Enforces enterprise instant messaging policy." Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no" Vital="yes" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
      <wix:ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes" OnUninstall="no"/>
      <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="60" ResetPeriodInDays="1" />
    </wix:ServiceInstall>
    <wix:ServiceControl Id="ABCWDStartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="ABCWD" Wait="yes" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" />

  </Component>

  <Component Id="SysABCMon.exe" Guid="*">
    <File Id="SysABCMon.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ClientSourceDirectory)\SysABCMon.exe" />
    <wix:ServiceInstall Id="SysABCMonServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Name="Service2" DisplayName="Service2" 
                        Description="Enforces enterprise instant messaging policy." Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no" Vital="yes" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
      <wix:ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes" OnUninstall="no"/>
      <util:ServiceConfig  FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="60" ResetPeriodInDays="1" />
    </wix:ServiceInstall>
    <wix:ServiceControl Id="SysABCMonStartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="SysABCMon" Wait="yes" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, got a solution after some hit and trial. In order to prevent the File in use ( or to prevent close the application prompt), we have to add the condition REMOVE for the CA ClientRemoveCustomAction - it just kills the desktop application.

```
 <Custom Action='ClientRemoveCustomAction' Before='InstallValidate'>
(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL") OR (REMOVE) <!--  For Unintall     and Upgrade, we need to ask the uninstall password-->
</Custom>
```

When the rollback is done, the service was not started so we have to add following custom action to start the service in case of rollback.
We need to understand that the CA should be sequenced as early as possible so that it would be executed at last in rollback.

```
<Custom Action='StartServiceIfNotRunningIdRoll' After='InstallInitialize'>
 (Installed)  <!--This is only for restart the service in case of Rollback.--> 
</Custom>
```

Please let me know if there could be any better solution.